# Flower Identification: Pyrenees, France

Tags: flowers

I'm trying to identify the white flowers in this photo. Location is in the Pyrenees mountains near Luz-Saint-Saveur in France. The image was shot in early September of this year. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Robert

[image: white flowers]